# What is the distance returned by Vuforia Image Tracking

Tags: unity-game-engine, computer-vision, augmented-reality, vuforia

Currently, I'm evaluating the image tracking accuracy of Vuforia for an application on the HoloLens 2 deployed using Unity3D.

I am comparing the distance values returned by Vuforia with the actual distance between HoloLens very front of the glasses and the image. For that I'm taking the distance between `Camera.main.transform.position` and `mObserverBehaviour.transform.position` of the image target.

For example, given an image target at the distance of 80cm measured from the front of the HL to the target, a deviation of about 6-7cm, meaning 86/87cm, can always be observed. I'm wondering, if maybe the distance returned does not refer to the distance between the front of the HoloLens and the target but rather the users face.

Does anybody know anything specific in that regard or can point me to some resources?

EDIT: As pointed out by others, the distance returned may refer to the distance between target and center of users head. If so, how could I precisely evaluate the accuracy of vuforia image distance tracking?

Comment: can you take a yard stick and validate both numbers?

Comment: You mean the extra distance to the face? Or what exactly? I am checking the distance in real world which deviates by 6-7cms.

Comment: "***by***...", yes, but that's a ***difference*** of distances. those operations give you ***absolute*** distances. please measure them, report the real distance as well as the distances claimed by both visual approaches.

Comment: I have edited my question, I still don't know what the point of absolute distances here is but I have included the information now. Basically, distance HL and target is 80cm in real world. Returned is 80+6cm. I have rephrased my question, maybe now it has become more clear. Looking forward to your input

Comment: does that mean that both the hololens AND "vuforia tracking" give you the same 86 cm figure?

Comment: How could I get the hololens tracking values to compare? I only have the values provided by Vuforia.

Comment: ah! I was under the impression that you did get distance values _from_ the hololens as well. my bad. -- if you measure (voforia) various distances for which you know the true distance, is it always the same difference (an offset), or does it increase with distance (a factor)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252536/discussion-between-anjelomerte-and-christoph-rackwitz).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how are you extracting the distances from the Vuforia or Hololens output. I guess you are looking at some Target poses. If this is the case please note that the the device frame of reference (the origin of the coordinate system) is the center of rotation of the user head, not the front of the glasses (as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/native/coordinate-systems-in-directx). This could explain a difference of 5-15cm from you measurement.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information! Already helps! I have rephrased my question based on your information, maybe now it's more clear

Comment: I am not a Unity expert but one would have to figure out what is the origin on the `Camera.main.transform.position` coordinate system. If this is the position of the RGB camera then it would not be that hard to measure distances from there